# Create a Sharepoint 2007 Page Layout that can be used to create new pages

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint

I am trying to replace some of the, frankly dreadful, out of box page layouts in Sharepoint 2007.

I have followed the [documentation provided by Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-publishing-page-layout-HA010174128.aspx) but this does not result in my page layout appearing in the Page Layouts list on Create Page.

Has anyone had success following Microsoft's instructions?  Is there a missing step here?